# How to stream from Digital Ocean Spaces using Video.js

Tags: stream, video.js, digital-ocean-spaces

I am trying to stream video and audio files to the video.js player on my site from Digital Ocean Spaces, which is similar to Amazon AWS S3 and uses the aws-sdk. Currently the video takes a while to download and then when the download completes, it plays. I would like to have it download in chunks and begin playing the first chunk as soon as it completes. How can I achieve this?
Here is my existing player code:

```
                         <html>
                          <head>
                          <link href="//unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                          <script src="//unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
                          </head> 
                          <body>
                          <div >
                          <video
                            id="my-player"
                            class="video-js"
                            controls
                            preload="auto"
                            data-setup='{}'
                            width=640 height=auto
                           >
                            <source src = "[VIDEO SOURCE URL]" type = "video/mp4">
                          </video>     
                          </div>                     
                          </body>
                        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution was to generate a presigned url, then use that for embedding into the html5 video/audio players. The DigitalOcean Api provided some excellent examples: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/resources/s3-sdk-examples/#presigned-url